# Error when deploying an EAR containing EJB and EJBClient to websphere

Tags: eclipse, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

We are running into a weird situation with a websphere application.

We developed this application in Eclipse Juno with websphere 8.5 server.  It is a JSF 2.0 application. It also has EJBTimer defined.  When testing this application locally, it works fine the JSF pages come up and also the EJBTimer also works as expected.

- When we built the application using our regular build process -
  extracting the code from clearcase and performimg an ANT build, the
  application gets deployed but complains about a method not found in
  local interface of the ejb. When we check the built EAR, the method
  is there in the interface.
- When we tried to export this as Export -> EAR and deployed that EAR
  on our development server, we get the below error.  Rememebr, the
  same code works on the local windows environment.  We also checked
  the compiler version of all the projects - web, ejb, ejbclient and
  all of them are Java 1.7.  Where else do we need to look at?

  ```
  [*Error] ejbModule/com/abc/appname/service/ProcessDailyFeed.java(54): Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7
  [*Error] ejbModule/com/abc/appname/scheduledBean/ScheduledBean.java(68): Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7
  ```

**UPDATE:**

*Output from Erroneous Deploy*

```
=== wasd8100Cell:Deploy Failed ===
=== Check http://serverabc:12345/Deployment_EAR_log for detail ===

Submitted By: b3601
    ------ Deploying Application -----------
    Ear File: myApp_dev_1.ear
    App Name: myApp
    Install Type: UPDATE
    Target: ('srv01_cluster', '')
    Target Http: ('https-web01', 'wasd8101')('https-web01', '')('https-web01', 'wasd8104')
    Modified Target Http: ('https-web01', 'wasd8101')('https-web01', 'wasd8104')
    Copy ear file from nfs to local filesystem /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_1.ear - 1.0s
    Virtual Host: default_host
    (Module, URI): ('MyAppEJB', 'MyAppEJB.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml')('MyAppWeb', 'MyAppWeb.war,WEB-INF/web.xml')
Bean: OracleDatabaseAccess
Bean: JPAReasonManager
Bean: JpaHistoryManager
Bean: JpaHistoryManager
Bean: ProcessDailyFeed
Bean: AccessExternal
Bean: MyAppService
Bean: ScheduledUpdateDatabase
Bean: ScheduledBean
Bean: StartUp
Bean: OracleDatabaseAccess
Bean: JPAReasonManager
Bean: JpaHistoryManager
Bean: ProcessDailyFeed
Bean: AccessExternal
Bean: MyAppService
Bean: ScheduledUpdateDatabase
Bean: ScheduledBean
Bean: StartUp
EJBDeploy = true

Run ejbdeploy.sh : /opt/local/software/websphere/v8/bin/ejbdeploy.sh -cp /ora01/oracle/product/was8/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_1.ear /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_1.ear_ejb.ear -quiet > /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp.out
using JVM heap -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
EJB Deploy configuration directory: /opt/local/software/websphere/v8/profiles/dmgr01/ejbdeploy/configuration/
framework search path: /opt/local/software/websphere/v8/deploytool/itp/plugins
build:RAD851-I20121103_1921
[*Error] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/service/ProcessDailyFeed.java(54): Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7
[*Error] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/scheduledBean/ScheduledBean.java(68): Multi-catch parameters are not allowed for source level below 1.7
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/scheduledBean/ScheduledBean.java(80): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivityHistory>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/scheduledBean/ScheduledBean.java(167): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivityHistory>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(67): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivityHistory>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(110): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<Long>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(121): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivity>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(160): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivityHistory>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(217): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivityHistory>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(267): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivityHistory>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(292): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivityHistory>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(314): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<String>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(348): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivityHistory>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(372): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivity>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(375): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivityHistory>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JpaHistoryManager.java(408): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<ProgramProductivityHistory>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JPAReasonManager.java(97): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<String>
[*Warning] ejbModule/com/abc/productivity/dao/JPAReasonManager.java(207): Type safety: Unchecked cast from List to List<EmergencyReason>
Execution Halted: Compilation Errors Reported
2 Errors, 16 Warnings, 0 Informational Messages

Deploy EJB ear file from /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_1.ear_ejb.ear

*** Invoke AdminApp Install *** 2015-02-20 07:25:00

AdminApp.install (/opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_1.ear_ejb.ear,[ -appname myApp -installed.ear.destination /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/myApp -MapModulesToServers [["MyAppEJB" MyAppEJB.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml WebSphere:cell=wasd8100Cell,cluster=srv01_cluster]["MyAppWeb" MyAppWeb.war,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:cell=wasd8100Cell,cluster=srv01_cluster+WebSphere:cell=wasd8100Cell,node=wasd8101,server=https-web01+WebSphere:cell=wasd8100Cell,node=wasd8104,server=https-web01]] -MapWebModToVH [["MyAppWeb" MyAppWeb.war,WEB-INF/web.xml default_host]] -update  -usedefaultbindings -defaultbinding.ejbjndi.prefix ejb -defaultbinding.virtual.host default_host -nopreCompileJSPs -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled -nodeployws -validateinstall off -noprocessEmbeddedConfig -nodeployejb -filepermission .*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink ])

=== deployEntApps with Exception === 2015-02-20 07:25:00
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/opt/softdepot/abcinst/was8scripts/abcUtils.py", line 2556, in deployEntApps
    installResults = AdminApp.install(installableEar,installOptions)
com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7115E: Cannot read input file "/opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_1.ear_ejb.ear"
```

*Output from good Deploy*

```
=== wasd8100Cell:Deploy Successful ===

Submitted By: b3601
    ------ Deploying Application -----------
    Ear File: myApp_dev_31.ear
    App Name: myApp
    Install Type: UPDATE
    Target: ('srv01_cluster', '')
    Target Http: ('https-web01', 'wasd8101')('https-web01', '')('https-web01', 'wasd8104')
    Modified Target Http: ('https-web01', 'wasd8101')('https-web01', 'wasd8104')
    Copy ear file from nfs to local filesystem /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_31.ear - 0.0s
    Virtual Host: default_host
    (Module, URI): ('MyAppEJB', 'MyAppEJB.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml')('MyAppWeb', 'MyAppWeb.war,WEB-INF/web.xml')

    Bean: OracleDatabaseAccess
    Bean: JPAReasonManager
    Bean: JpaHistoryManager
    Bean: JpaHistoryManager
    Bean: ProcessDailyFeed
    Bean: AccessExternal
    Bean: MyAppService
    Bean: ScheduledUpdateDatabase
    Bean: ScheduledBean
    Bean: StartUp
    Bean: OracleDatabaseAccess
    Bean: JPAReasonManager
    Bean: JpaHistoryManager
    Bean: ProcessDailyFeed
    Bean: AccessExternal
    Bean: MyAppService
    Bean: ScheduledUpdateDatabase
    Bean: ScheduledBean
    Bean: StartUp
    EJBDeploy = true

    Run ejbdeploy.sh : /opt/local/software/websphere/v8/bin/ejbdeploy.sh -cp /ora01/oracle/product/was8/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_31.ear /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_31.ear_ejb.ear -quiet > /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp.out
    using JVM heap -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
    EJB Deploy configuration directory: /opt/local/software/websphere/v8/profiles/dmgr01/ejbdeploy/configuration/
    framework search path: /opt/local/software/websphere/v8/deploytool/itp/plugins
    build:RAD851-I20121103_1921
    0 Errors, 0 Warnings, 0 Informational Messages

    Deploy EJB ear file from /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_31.ear_ejb.ear

    *** Invoke AdminApp Install *** 2015-02-20 07:28:48

    AdminApp.install (/opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/tmp/myApp_dev_31.ear_ejb.ear,[ -appname myApp -installed.ear.destination /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/myApp -MapModulesToServers [["MyAppEJB" MyAppEJB.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml WebSphere:cell=wasd8100Cell,cluster=srv01_cluster]["MyAppWeb" MyAppWeb.war,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:cell=wasd8100Cell,cluster=srv01_cluster+WebSphere:cell=wasd8100Cell,node=wasd8101,server=https-web01+WebSphere:cell=wasd8100Cell,node=wasd8104,server=https-web01]] -MapWebModToVH [["MyAppWeb" MyAppWeb.war,WEB-INF/web.xml default_host]] -update  -usedefaultbindings -defaultbinding.ejbjndi.prefix ejb -defaultbinding.virtual.host default_host -nopreCompileJSPs -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled -nodeployws -validateinstall off -noprocessEmbeddedConfig -nodeployejb -filepermission .*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink ])
    *** AdminApp Install Complete *** 2015-02-20 07:28:56

    Deployed Location : /opt/local/software/abcnstalledApps/myApp/myApp.ear
    Class Loader Policy : MULTIPLE (SINGLE=Application,MULTIPLE=Module)
    Class Loader Mode : PARENT_FIRST

    *** Saving the deployemnt *** 2015-02-20 07:28:56

    Old Context Root: myApp
    New Context Root: myApp
    Same Context root, no need to genPlugin

    *** Generate docs cache deployment request **** 2015-02-20 07:29:00

    Duration: 44.0s

    *** It may take up to 5-10 minutes for the ear file completely written to each node. Please have a nice coffee break:-)
    *** Check http://serverabc:12345/Deployment_EAR_log for detail.
```

Comment: Looks like your development server is using is using Java 1.6 instead of 1.7. Remember that by default WAS 8.5 is using Java 1.6 and you have to manually install 1.7 and switch server to use 1.7.

Comment: Of course, that is the first thing that comes to mind, and even though it is not likely for the below reason - we still checked that and it is 1.7. When we do the build with the same code that has multi-catch using the build script - buildforge/ANT - and deploy that, we don't receive this particular error. We receive the error only when we try to deploy the EAR exported from the Eclipse project. That is why I was thinking, there may be something missing in the project set-up in Eclipse which comes into play when creating an EAR ( it also runs locally without issues ), that we may have missed.

Comment: When exactly are you getting these errors (during export, install, start, first request)? As this doesn't look like error from the `SystemOut.log`. And I'd say that this is rather compiler error, not runtime error.   I've seen similar errors in Eclipse during build (even when compiler is 1.7 you may have source set to 1.6), but not on the server during deployment/runtime.

Comment: It is happening at deploy time. I have added the outputs of our deploy scripts. Multiple people checked the compiler settings on the projects in Eclipse and that is set to 1.7 unless we have forgotten to check some other setting

Comment: Is it from same environment, just 2 different ears, or different environments?

Comment: Same environment - 2 different ears for the same application - but the EARs built differently - One EAR is from the buildforge ANT buildscript that is used for all our applications and that is the one that deploys correctly - the other EAR is exported from Eclipse workspace that errors out.  **Note:** The same code that is in the Eclipse ( Clearcase ) is what is used with the ANT build

Answer (score 0):

It's now a bit clear. The error is during ejbdeploy call. First of all you don't need to call ejbdeploy, if your app is using ejb 3.x (it is only required for older apps, so you may safely remove that call from your script for 3.x). Second, I'd compare `application.xml` and `ejb-jar.xml` files from both EARs - the one generated by your build script and one created by Eclipse. The ejbdeploy uses `complianceLevel`, see more [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.etools.ejbbatchdeploy.doc/topics/regenc.html?lang=en)

```
  -complianceLevel X   Set the JDK level X for compiler compliance to one of: 1.4(default), 5.0, 6.0, 7.0
```

which is calculated using following rules:

> If the -complianceLevel option for the ejbdeploy command is not
>   specified, in any of the following cases the default -complianceLevel
>   setting is Java developer kit V5.0, "5.0":
>
> - An EAR or JAR file that contains Java EE 5 (or later) or EJB 3.0 (or later) deployment descriptor files
> - An EAR file without any deployment descriptor files
>
> All other cases, the -complianceLevel setting defaults to Java
>   developer kit V1.4, "1.4"

So I'd say that probably your Eclipse export has descriptor, which changes that `complianceLevel`.

Try to add to your ejbdeploy call flag `-complianceLevel "7.0"`

Comment: Acutually I checked using the winmerge and both of them have the deployment descriptors for EAR and EJB ( i.e. application.xml and ejb-jar.xml, but the file sizes are different - the one that fails is 7019KB the good one is 6972 KB - so there is somthing definitely different in the Eclipse generated one. Also, I see "File "/opt/softdepot/abcinst/was8scripts/abcUtils.py", line 2556, in deployEntApps" in the output and the abcUtils.py is a homegrown script that uses the IBM provided scripts.  I will wotk with our WAS admin to see what is the difference between the two EARs

Comment: @adbdkb - Did you ever figure out what the solution was; I'm facing something similar.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Since our WAS admin group is different and developers do not have access / permissions to perform these functions, I was not able to do any trial and error and get it resolved